# Django - My first app, stuck at the model

Tags: python, django, model

I am new to Django and trying to create my first app.
This is an app that is called logo, and is supposed to store logos that can be displayed in the base.html.

This is my current model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Logo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default = "LogoName")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(("is active"), default = False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    date_created = models.DateField(verbose_name="Created on date", auto_now_a$
    image_field = models.FileField("Image", upload_to='images/')
```

This is how it looks in admin:
[image]

The problems at this point is:

**1)** How do I set the Logo object name?

**2)** How can I only set the current user, and not pick from the dropdown menu?

**3)** And the biggest problem, when I follow the image link after saving the logo object, I get an 404 error.
This is how the url looks like:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/logo/logo/4/images/80s_BG_1.jpg/ - I do have created an "images" folder in the logo app folder. But the link seems adding the primary key "4" in this case. Why? And how to get store the uploaded image?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

concerning 1) add the following to your model

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % (self.name)
```

concerning 2) You have to update your admin.py and put something like that in there:

```
class LogoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, item, form, change):
        if not item.id:
            item.owner = request.user

        super(LogoAdmin, self).save_model(request, item, form, change)

[...]

admin.site.register(Logo, LogoAdmin)
```

in your model set:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User,editable=False)
```

I have not tested it, but think this is the way to go.

concerning 3) As the others wrote, you have update your settings, I guess. But I was wondering: Is the picture actually uploaded to the folder?

Answer (score 0):

1.You can write `class Meta:
                     verbose_name = "LOGO"`
at model.

2.You must add User Model data.

3.Maybe you should modify the media url in the settings

Comment: Thank you for answering! **1)** Added your suggested code to the logos model.py - but the Logo Object has still the same name. **2)** How do I add User Model data? (sorry I am a but confused) **3)** I added this to the settings.py # Media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' the url is now http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/80s_BG_5.jpg But the img can still not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

1 - define the __unicode__ function for the model

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

2 - override the save method of the model to set the active user or use django signals

3 - Configure your MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT and then add this at the end of your main urls.py for development

```
if settings.DEBUG:
# static files (images, css, javascript, etc.)
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```